# Symfony AbstractToken private properties

Tags: symfony

I'm extending symfony's `AbstractToken` to fit my own needs. However, `AbstactToken` declares its properties `$user`, `$roles` and `$authenticated` as private. Furthermore, there is no `setRoles()`-function, it can only be initialized through the constructor.

This seems to not make sense: why should you provide the roles at the constructor and only then?

My expected control flow would be:

1. create an unauthenticated token with session info
2. find the user based on this info and set this in the token
3. perform some checks and based on that: `setAuthenticated(true);`
4. and add the roles the user has to the token

Step 4 isn't possible, so I think I misunderstand something about how tokens should be used, but reading the docs I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Because your flow does not match Symfony's flow, which is creating the token once with all the required information. Take a look at [UserAuthenticatedProvider](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php#L96) for an example. What kind of needs you have for your token?

Comment: It's needed to integrate Symfony with an authsystem already in place.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, in your workflow, if you authenticate a user, then he should not have a "anonymous token" anymore.

I think you're kinda mixing up responsabilities : an unauthenticated token should be, as its name implies it, for an unauthenticated user, and when he authenticate himself, it should be a `AuthenticatedToken` or something alike, with its own roles then, as you should know the roles of the user that was just authenticated.

But if you really want to have the same token through and through, you may instead of using the `AbstractToken` extends and implements an interface based on `TokenInterface`...

Comment: So the unauth-token could / should be a different class too? It just feels so natural to me to give someone a token at the start, and then flip the `$authenticated` to indicate authentication. You're right about implementing myself. It's just that I'd want to understand why Symfony expects it differently,

Comment: You can always change the token (having a `AuthenticatedToken` instead of the `UnauthenticatedToken`) in the security context though...

But yeah, implementing yourself a token that changes should be okay though, even though I wouldn't really recommend it